# Starting Ethereum Development

Tags: truffle, drizzle

Sorry for vague question but just looking to get some insight. I have just began developing a dapp for the ethereum network and I need some advice on what development frameworks/technologies to use.
I am fine with the Solidity smart contract development however I am struggling with the front-end UI and contract interaction.
Is drizzle a necessity when using truffle? 
Is react recommended or can I just use a node-js front-end and interact with web3-js.
Any advice would be great.
Thanks

Comment: You can use a node-js front-end but drizzle simplifies greatly simplifies contract interactions.

I recommend exploring the existing truffle boxes boilerplates, but for simple applications there is no downside to using a front-end to interact with web3, I think it would make you a better Ethereum dev :).

Answer (score 1):

you can use any front-end framework you want, but Dizzle provide a full integrated web3 layer that help for development process.

For example, I used web3.js with ember.js for some dApp test wich was working really well.